# “Will” and “going to” (Murphy's ‘Grammar in Use’ exercise)

Tags: grammar, future, will-be-going

Here is an example from Murphy's grammar textbook:

> You are in a restaurant. You and your friend are looking at the menu. Maybe your friend has decided what to have. You ask her/him.
>
> You: What ...?

The correct answer is "What are you going to have?" My question is: the decision is being made at the moment of speaking, so shouldn't it be "What WILL you have?"

Comment: Related: [“going to” vs “will”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will) and [When do I have to use 'will' instead of 'going to'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/when-do-i-have-to-use-will-instead-of-going-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When choosing a dish from a menu, there is no real discernible difference between “What will you have?” and “What are you going to have?”**

Both phrases are correct. Sometimes a restaurant customer already has an idea of what he wants to eat if he is familiar with the establishment. Sometimes a speaker wants to emphasize the element of intention, thus *going to* might be preferred. If both customers have been reading the menu for a couple of minutes, *going to* leans towards the intention or prediction aspect.  And sometimes it's just quicker to *say* “What'll you have?” There's nothing to suggest impoliteness or inappropriateness about either form.

However, I'd say the *will* form is more common when replying: *I'll have the spaghetti carbonara.*

Answer (score 0):

The question "what will you have ?" comes across as slightly more impatient and less friendly than "what are you going to have ?".
It's a subtle difference, but "what will you have ?" demands a more immediate answer than "what are you going to have ?".
I also imagine "what will you have ?" would be more acceptable and less impatient sounding in an American rather than in a British context.